# How to Delete a Record with Custom id in laravel by default its taking only ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

MY DB structure is like this

```
CREATE TABLE `subscription_manager` (
  `subscription_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `comic_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `admin_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_subscription` date NOT NULL,
  `mini` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `one_shots` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `updated_at` date NOT NULL,
  `created_at` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here subscription_id is the table primary key.

I am using join here to fetch data from 3 tables.

```
public function index()
    {
       $fetch = DB::table('subscription_manager')
            ->join('comic_info', 'comic_info.id', '=', 'subscription_manager.comic_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'subscription_manager.user_id')
            ->get();
        for ($i = 0, $c = count($fetch); $i < $c; ++$i) {
        $fetch[$i] = (array) $fetch[$i];
        }
        return view('comic/subcriptions', compact('fetch'));

    }
```

and here the destroy method

```
  public function destroy($id)
    {
      $subscribe = Subscription::find($id);
      if ($subscribe != null) 
      {
      $subscribe->delete();
      return redirect('subscriptions')->with('message','Subscription Successfully Deleted');
      }
         else
      {
        return redirect('subscriptions')->with('message','Unable to Delete');
       }
    }
```

And delete action is look like inside view.

```
<form action="{{ action('SubscriptionController@destroy', $comic['subscription_id'])}}" method="post">
                {{csrf_field()}}
            <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
          </form>
```

But when i going to delete the record it says

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'subscription_manager.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `subscription_manager` where `subscription_manager`.`id` = 191 limit 1)
```

That means its by default taking id only. I dont want delete from id. i want that from subscription_id.

How can i Fixed that issue thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you read up about this in the documentation you will find out there is a firstOrFail() method with a Where()

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

So in your destroy method you need to change

```
  $subscribe = Subscription::find($id);
```

to

```
  $subscribe = Subscription::where('subscription_id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: now its asking error like this  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `subscription_manager` where `id` is null)

Comment: And if you look in your database in the subscription_manager table?

Comment: and if you read the documentation about delete did you try `User::where('votes', '>', 100)->delete();` something like that?

Comment: I want to subscription_id as a primary key for the table subscription_manager. How can i do that? Laravel destroy method automatically finding by id. I want to use subscription_id instead of id.

Comment: Thanks alot man.!@works perfectly. I did this. $subscribe = Subscription::where('subscription_id', '=', $id)->delete();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157972/discussion-between-krishna-gupta-and-stuiterslurf).

Answer (score 0):

You can override laravel's [conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)
Just add `primaryKey` property to your model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'subscription_id';
```